# Best way to call hidden base class method

Tags: c++, overriding, hidden

In the following code, "d.Foo()" throws a compiler error claiming that function Foo() does not take 0 arguments.  Yet a 0-argument function with that name exists in the base class.  The line "d.Base::Foo()" is acceptable.

I have a vague memory of learning that the use of a function name in a derived class hides all functions of that name in a base class, even though arguments may be different.  I don't remember why, nor do I remember the best way to avoid that problem.  Is my solution best, or is there another way to get at Base::Foo()?

Thanks very much!

RobR

```
// Override.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
class Base
{
public :
    void Foo()
    {
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public: 
    void Foo(int x)
    {
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Derived d;
    d.Foo();
    d.Base::Foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks.  My question is indeed a duplicate of that one, and responses to that are quite good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define `Derived::Foo()` as:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void Foo() { Base::Foo(); }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use(!) base class member functions via `using`

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    using Base::Foo;
};
```